# "Could not open ServletContext resource" in test context

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I'm trying to create a Unit Test with Spring.

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyConfig.class})
public class MyTest{
@Test
public void ...
}
```

Class to load:

```
@ConfigurationProperties()
@PropertySource("config/myConfig.properties")
@Component
public class MyConfig {}
```

Exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to parse configuration class
>   [de.db.sus.converter.fia.business.algorithm.config.FiaConverterConfig];
>   nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open
>   ServletContext resource [/config/myConfig.properties]

I have found resources for web applications and/or xml based configurations, but wasn't apply to transfer them.

If I would start the application with `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`the properties get loaded. But I can't start the whole application for every Unit test.

I have verified that the file exists in the directory test/resources/config/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems that the requested properties can't be found. I would recommend doing this:

If the requested properties file is within your classpath you can fix above with just writing the next line:

`@PropertySource("classpath:config/myConfig.properties")`

Comment: Thanks, this helps. In short:  "classpath:" is missing

Answer (score 0):

I configured maven war plugin as below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
       <warName>${war-file-name}</warName>
        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <webResources>
          <resource>
            <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
          </resource>
        </webResources>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Configure the following section as relevant to your `pom.xml`

```
 <webResources>
          <resource>
            <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
          </resource>
 </webResources>
```

For more information refer [Adding and Filtering External Web Resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-war-plugin-2.4/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had same error but I had to define my resources file reference with `classpath` as I was loading file from properties file

```
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.key-store=classpath:/client-file
```

You can also load from filesystem - see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/resources.html)